# Why can't I used an exported bash function in a python3 subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

If I run the following in a bash shell:

```
function tempE(){ echo "This is tempE"; }
export -f tempE
python3 -c "import subprocess as sp; print(sp.run(['tempE'],capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf8'));"
```

... then I'd expect to get the message "This is tempE". Instead, I get a python3 error stack complaining that it can't find `tempE`. But I thought that this python3 process would have access to its parent-shell function `tempE` in virtue of the line `export -f tempE`.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell functions are implemented by the shell, so you need to execute the command through the shell. By default `subprocess.run()` executes the program directly, so use `shell=True` to make it use the shell.

Also, exported functions are a `bash` extension, but `subprocess.run()` uses `sh` by default. Use `executable='/bin/bash'` to override this.

```
python3 -c "import subprocess as sp; print(sp.run('tempE', shell=True, executable = '/bin/bash', capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf8'));"
```

Comment: If `sh` really is `bash`, it will still reconstruct the function definition found in the environment. You could also use `executable=...` to ensure `bash` is the shell used.

Comment: @chepner I assumed it wouldn't do this when executed as `sh`

Comment: I was somewhat surprised that it did as well.

Comment: But on many systems these days `sh` is `dash`